# Can you use raven to get incident details?

Tags: python, logging, sentry, raven

I know that you can use raven to log exceptions in Sentry - is there a method that lets you read data from stuff previously logged in Sentry? e.g. if I have the incident id, can I read its additional data? The documentation is very terse and I didn't see any such examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the generated event ID you can use the Sentry API to pull down data for it:

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/api/events/get-project-event-details/

Comment: Yeah I was looking into the API - I would prefer not to write my own HTTP requests but I will do that if I can't the functionality in raven.